# Is there an $x$ such that $\cos(x)=\sin(x)=0$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trigonometry, discrete-calculus

How do I show this in proofs? All I know is that there is no one value of $x$ that will make both $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ equal to $0$, but I'm unsure how to prove it other than mentioning what I just said.

Let $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x)=\cos x$. Let $D$ be the collection of real numbers and consider the propositional functions with the domain of definition $D$ defined by $P(x):f(x)=0$ and $Q(x):g(x) = 0$ when $x$ is a real number. In other words for a real number $x$, $P(x)$ is the
proposition $f(x) = 0$ and $Q(x)$ is defined similarly.

Let $R$ be the statement $∃x, P(x)∧Q(x)$. Is $R$ true or false?

Comment: Do you know that $\cos$ and $\sin$ are the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of points on the unit circle?

Comment: Fundamental relationship $\cos^2 x +\sin^2 x = 1$ prevents them to be both zero...

Comment: With the usual geometric definition of cosx, sinx the statement is clearly false. Unless you define sinx and cosx in a different way! It will again be false but it may need some proof!

Comment: If you want a rigorous proof, you'll have to specify how sine and cosine are defined.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose there was a point $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\cos x=\sin x=0.$$

Then we would have

$$0=\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1,$$

which is a contradiction. Thus such a point cannot exist.